# FireBase задваиваются Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, уведомления

При отправке уведомления (читай пуш-сообщения) из консоли (console.firebase.google.com) на мобильное устройство приходят 2 уведомления. Это такой механизм работы или "косяк"?

Comment: Должен быть косяк. Видать у вас дважды приёмщик сообщения зарегистрирован/отраатывает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  а если отсылаю не из консоли, а с кастомного решения - то приходит одно уведомление. Служба вроде одна крутится. Ок, буду искать "косяк"

Comment: Хм... Ну, вообще они ж недавно обновление крупное сделали, так что может и у FireBase косяк...

Comment: Скорей всего классика onRecieve - дважды